# How to reverse a sublevel items in a multiindex dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I want to do a time series analysis and I want that each sublevel (level=delta_mins) get reversed for each date. So basically I want to transform df1 to df2.

df1

```
date      delta_mins      A   B   C
2019-12-2   20            a1  b1  c1
            30            a2  b2  c2
            40            a3  b3  c3  
            50            a4  b4  c4
            60            a5  b5  c5
2019-12-3   20            d1  e1  f1
            30            d2  e2  f2
            40            d3  e3  f3
            50            d4  e4  f4
            60            d5  e5  f5
2019-12-4   20            g1  h1  i1
            30            g2  h2  i2
            40            g3  h3  i3
            50            g4  h4  i4
            60            g5  h5  i5
```

transform to 
df2

```
date      delta_mins      A   B   C
2019-12-2   60            a5  b5  c5
            50            a4  b4  c4
            40            a3  b3  c3  
            30            a2  b2  c2
            20            a1  b1  c1
2019-12-3   60            d5  e5  f5
            50            d4  e4  f4   
            40            d3  e3  f3
            30            d2  e2  f2
            20            d1  e1  f1
2019-12-4   60            g5  h5  i5
            50            g4  h4  i4
            40            g3  h3  i3 
            30            g2  h2  i2
            20            g1  h1  i1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I beleive you need [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) with `ascending=False` for second level:

```
df = df.sort_index(level=[0, 1], ascending=[True, False])
print (df)
                        A   B   C
date       delta_mins            
2019-12-02 60          a5  b5  c5
           50          a4  b4  c4
           40          a3  b3  c3
           30          a2  b2  c2
           20          a1  b1  c1
2019-12-03 60          d5  e5  f5
           50          d4  e4  f4
           40          d3  e3  f3
           30          d2  e2  f2
           20          d1  e1  f1
2019-12-04 60          g5  h5  i5
           50          g4  h4  i4
           40          g3  h3  i3
           30          g2  h2  i2
           20          g1  h1  i1
```

If not possible you can create helper level by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), sorting and last drop it:

```
df = (df.set_index(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)
        .sort_index(level=[0, 2], ascending=[True, False])
        .reset_index(level=2, drop=True))
print (df)
                        A   B   C
date       delta_mins            
2019-12-02 60          a5  b5  c5
           50          a4  b4  c4
           40          a3  b3  c3
           30          a2  b2  c2
           20          a1  b1  c1
2019-12-03 60          d5  e5  f5
           50          d4  e4  f4
           40          d3  e3  f3
           30          d2  e2  f2
           20          d1  e1  f1
2019-12-04 60          g5  h5  i5
           50          g4  h4  i4
           40          g3  h3  i3
           30          g2  h2  i2
           20          g1  h1  i1
```